# The number of root for a complex number?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I was doing a homework to find the Cartesian form for all values of $e^{i\pi/4}$.

However, if I saw it as an exact number, there is only one answer $\cos(\pi/4)+i\sin(\pi/4)$. That was, $(1,\pi/4)$. However, if we saw $e^{i\pi/4}=(e^{i\pi/2})^{1/2}$. Obviously, there were two answers.

Similiar, we treat any number in polar form $(r,\theta)$ to be $(r^n,n\theta)^{1/n}$.

My questions were:

1, What was the answer for "all values" of $e^{i\pi/4}$ in Cartesian form $(x+iy)$?

2, What went wrong when I treat $(r,\theta)$ to be $(r^n,n\theta)^{1/n}$? How many values did a complex number have?

Comment: Your misunderstanding is similar to how many roots do $x^2 = 4$ have. When squaring and equation you generated some redundant roots.

Comment: The first line of your question is like saying you want to find all values of $3$. $e^{i\pi/4}$ has just one value, namely $e^{i\pi/4}$.

Comment: The context of the question was very misleading. $e^{i\pi/4}$ was part (c). I got $i^{1/4}$ in part (b) and none of them specified if they were seeking for the 4th order of root or just find a Cartesian form. What were the answers suppose to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By taking square, you added an extraneous solution. For example, if $x=1$ then $x^2 = 1$. But $x^2=1 \implies x=\pm 1$. So we have added an extra solution $x=-1$ by applying squares on both sides of $x=1$.